# filter data.frame conditional on ordered factor in R

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements

I have a large dataframe in long format which I want to convert to wide format at a later stage. There are entries per StudyId by several annotators. I want to filter the dataframe to only contain entries per StudyID of only one annotator. Preferably, following a hierarchy of the annotators. Meaning, if the first AnnotatorID (of some list) is present keep these entries, if not look for the second in line and so forth.

Here is some sample code to replicate:

```
StudyId <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c")
AnnotatorId <- c("Frank", "Frank", "Steffi", "Steffi", "Steffi", "Max", "Max", "Toni", "Frank", "Frank", "Annabelle", "Annabelle")

a <- data.frame(StudyId, AnnotatorId)
```

The data.frame consists of appr. 160 variables and more than 3000 observations. The IDs are simplified in this example but in my dataframe they consist of a mixture of digits and letters like: "034e6cee-79e8-4e67-a27a-1ee2c187eaf4". Neither working by alphabetical order or highest value does most likely help, I guess.

So far, I tried to order the levels of AnnotatorId but do not know how to loop over all entries and keep only AnnotatorIds in order of appearance in the factor.

```
a$AnnotatorId <- factor(a$AnnotatorId, 
                        levels = c(
                          "Max",
                          "Annabelle",
                          "Toni",
                          "Steffi",
                          "Frank"
                        ), ordered = TRUE)
```

In the end I would like to have something like:

| StudyId | AnnotatorId |
| --- | --- |
| a | Steffi |
| a | Steffi |
| a | Steffi |
| b | Max |
| b | Max |
| c | Annabelle |
| c | Annabelle |

I am a programming novice. So any help and kind guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group_by StudyId and `filter`:

```r
StudyId <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c")
AnnotatorId <- c("Frank", "Frank", "Steffi", "Steffi", "Steffi", "Max", "Max", "Toni", "Frank", "Frank", "Annabelle", "Annabelle")
a <- data.frame(StudyId, AnnotatorId)

a$AnnotatorId <- factor(a$AnnotatorId, 
                        levels = rev(c(
                          "Max",
                          "Annabelle",
                          "Toni",
                          "Steffi",
                          "Frank"
                        )), ordered = TRUE)

a %>% 
   group_by(StudyId) %>% 
   filter(AnnotatorId == max(AnnotatorId))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 7 × 2
# Groups:   StudyId [3]
  StudyId AnnotatorId
  <chr>   <ord>      
1 a       Steffi     
2 a       Steffi     
3 a       Steffi     
4 b       Max        
5 b       Max        
6 c       Annabelle  
7 c       Annabelle
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple easy solution. I had thought in the same direction but somehow didn't manage to.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against ordering nominal values on ordinal scale. An ordinary `factor` is sufficient, since it's underlying integer structure is already "ordered" according to the levels starting with `1`. Just use `min` in `ave`.

```
hier <- c("Max", "Annabelle", "Toni", "Steffi", "Frank")
a <- transform(a, AnnotatorId=factor(AnnotatorId, levels = hier))

a[as.logical(ave(as.integer(a$AnnotatorId), a$StudyId, FUN=\(x) x == min(x))), ]
#    StudyId AnnotatorId
# 3        a      Steffi
# 4        a      Steffi
# 5        a      Steffi
# 6        b         Max
# 7        b         Max
# 11       c   Annabelle
# 12       c   Annabelle
```

---

*Data:*

```
a <- structure(list(StudyId = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "c", "c", "c", "c"), AnnotatorId = c("Frank", "Frank", "Steffi", 
"Steffi", "Steffi", "Max", "Max", "Toni", "Frank", "Frank", "Annabelle", 
"Annabelle")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: I do have to admit that I don't understand fully what is done here. I understand the underlying structure of the factor and that min(x) looks for the lowest value. Why is the as.logical() function needed in the beginning?

Comment: @Torsten So if you look into help page `?ave`,  it splits `value`s into `group`s, applies a function `FUN` and ungroups back, `ave(value, group, FUN=func)`.  The function `x == min(x)` checks for each element in each group _if_ it is the group minimum. The result is actually boolean, however it is coerced into binary integers `0`or `1` after ungrouping (because `value` is integer) which we may coerce `as.logical`, though, which finally allows the subsetting of data frame `a`.